# I am getting an error `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable` on my loss function

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am getting the error `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable` when I run this block of code:

```
torch.manual_seed(50)
epoch = 5
train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
for epochs in range(epoch):
  for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    model.train()
    y_logits = model(X)
    print(y_logits.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    loss = loss(y_logits, y)
    train_loss += loss
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

the error is happening on my loss function. Here is the code where I created that:

```
!pip install torchmetrics
from torchmetrics.classification import MulticlassAccuracy
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params=model.parameters(),
                            lr=0.01)
```

any idea on how to solve this error?

Comment: Don't name your variable `loss`. That's the name of the function, so on the next iteration  you can't call the function because you've replaced it with the returned-value.

Answer (score 0):

```
loss = loss(y_logits, y)
train_loss += loss
```

function name and variable name should be different.